# Can I invoke a lambda right after it's created using aws_cdk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

With the code below I can create and deploy a lambda, but I wanted to invoke it every time a deploy is performed. This code runs in github actions workflow .

```
import os

from aws_cdk import (
    core as cdk,
    aws_lambda as lambda_,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_stepfunctions as invoke
)

class DMSAutoBackfill(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        lambda_fn = lambda_.Function(
            self, "DmsAutoFillLambda",
            code=lambda_.Code.from_asset(
                os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), "lambda_function")
            ),
            handler="create_dms_backfill.event_handler",
            environment={
                'schema_name': os.getenv('schema_name', ''),
                'table_name': os.getenv('table_name', '')
            },
            timeout=cdk.Duration.seconds(ADD_EMR_STEP_LAMBDA_TIMEOUT),
            runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
        )
```

I've tried using `CustomResource` also from `aws_cdk` but it didn't work, it only runs the lambda after its creation (the first time the cloudformation resources were created) and not after each call of the github actions (where an update was generated on the cloudformation resources).

**Update**

I chose to create a script using `boto3` to invoke the lambda, and call using Github Actions.

I came to the conclusion that the `CDK` is better to be used to create and manage infra as codes, whereas `boto3` is better to operate these created resources.

Comment: Please expand upon "it didn't work". FYI, custom resources need to be coded differently to normal Lambda functions because they need to 'return' in a special way to continue execution of the CloudFormation template.

Comment: If you use GitHub Actions, why not invoke the lambda with that?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I added more information.

Comment: @Chiel I ended up using github actions to call a script that invokes lambda, I added an update to the question.

Comment: Sounds indeed as the right conclusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda can be triggered during/after the CDK deployment, it can be done using TriggerFunction

```
new triggers.TriggerFunction(stack, 'MyTrigger', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
  handler: 'index.handler',
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(__dirname + '/my-trigger'),
});
```

Node JS Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_triggers.TriggerFunction.html

Python Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.triggers/Trigger.html#trigger

Answer (score 2):

In case someone finds this question I wanted to show a way to do this using cdk.

You can use `AwsCustomResource` to invoke AWS commands with your stack.

From the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsCustomResource.html

> Defines a custom resource that is materialized using specific AWS API calls.
>
> Use this to bridge any gap that might exist in the CloudFormation Coverage. You can specify exactly which calls are invoked for the 'CREATE', 'UPDATE' and 'DELETE' life cycle events.

This custom resource will spin up a lambda function that executes the aws cli command you specified.

Make sure that you the resource is granted permission to call the function. You can do this by assinging a policy or using the grant helpers ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsCustomResource.html#policy ):

> The custom resource also implements iam.IGrantable, making it possible to use the grantXxx() methods.

Comment: Try this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks/LambdaInvoke.html